# can we throw any error or exception explicitly using throw

Tags: java, exception

Since JVM Exceptions are those exceptions or errors that are either exclusively or most logically thrown by the JVM.

Programmatic exceptions are those exceptions that are thrown explicitly by application and/or API programmers using throw keyword.

Now coming to exception hierarchy: which basically divided into 3 major categories: I am relating to the above category i.e. JVM Exceptions  and Programmatic Exception.

1. Unchecked (Error & RunTimeException) : JVM or Programmatic
2. Checked Exception : Programmatic.

[How to differentiate between Programmer and JVM Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933832/how-to-differentiate-between-programmer-and-jvm-exceptions)

I am reading the above link where two things burst into my mind and I want to verify them

1. Can we throw any error programmatically since JVM generated exceptions can be throw programatically.
2. What is the significance of generating JVMException programmatically i.e. when should we throw JVM generated exceptions programmatically
3. In the above link " Chris Lively" wrote AsserionError can not be throw programatically which should be wrong.

Comment: The answers to the question that you linked to make it awfully clear that there is no difference between "JVM exceptions" and "programmer exceptions".  They are not different kinds of objects. The distinction you are drawing here is not useful or meaningful. So yes of course you can throw any kind of exception.

Comment: You can, so far as I know, throw any exception (Throwable subclass) that's defined.  It would be possible to design a Throwable subclass that could only be thrown by JNI or which embedded some authorization check within it to only allow it's construction by certain environments, but I know of no such case.

Comment: Now more specific,NullPointerException is JVM generated.When should I throw it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

The most valued answer to the referenced question says: "no such distinction exists". I can only agree with this sentence. So, (i) yes, (ii) if there is some reason to do so, say, an intermediate method calls system method, catches a "JVM" exception, and rethrows it, (iii) AssertionError well can be thrown as any other Throwable.

Comment: Your (ii) case answer is about rethrowing a unchecked exception as checked exception.I'm asking when it is feasible to throw a exception like "NullPointerException" programmatically using throw

Comment: If you implement an existing interface whose docs requires NullPointerException (e.g.java.lang.Readable#read). In other cases, more meaningful exceptions prefereed (like IllegalArgumentException).

Answer (score 0):

Your exception hierarchy can "borrow" classes from the standard library if it makes sense (e.g. IllegalArgumentException can be used for application-specific input validation and IndexOutOfBoundsException can be used for any data structure with numeric indices) but since you are concerned with exceptions thrown by your code whether these classes belong in a vaguely defined set of JVM-thrown exceptions is irrelevant.

Checked vs unchecked is also a less than fundamental distinction: the same exception class, thrown from the same places and caught in the same places with the same handling, can be either.
You might prefer the convenience of ensuring that a checked exception is caught or the convenience of not adding boring *throws* clauses for an unchecked exception, and you can change your mind easily.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a bank application that sends an alert message when the saving amount becomes zero or less then zero.

```
 public class AmountZeroException extends Exception
 {
 }

 public class SavingAmount
 {
    public private int amount;
   public void PrintAmountFromSaving()throws AmountZeroException
   {
     System.out.println("your account balance is "+amount);
     if(amount<=0)
     throw AmountZEroEXception();
   }


   public static void main(String...k)
   {
     SavingAmount sa=new SavingAmount();
     System.out.println(sa.PrintAmountFromSaving());
   }
 }
```

In this example above

1. *We Can we throw any error programmatically since JVM generated exceptions can be throw programatically.*
2. What is the significance of generating JVMException programmatically i.e. when should we throw JVM generated exceptions programmatically

   *hear in the above example I also can throw JVMException programatically by using any of the exception viz ArrayIndexOutOfBount or any other. but the significance depends upon the usage of the application. since my application is all about sending alert when amount becomes zero so I used Pro-grammatically my own exception.*